# Pinterest Dynamic Pin update

Tags: reactjs, pinterest

I am using the Pinterest public API (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/pin-widget/) on a local project.

I am able to display Pinterest pins ON LOAD but not during subsequent renders.

For a snippet like this `<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/139752394664775546/" data-pin-do="embedPin"> </a>`

I wish to dynamically pass in an pinId like so     `` <a href={`https://www.pinterest.com/pin/${PIN_ID}/`} data-pin-do="embedPin"> </a> `` Where PIN_ID is dynamic and the element will rerender to grab the latest pin information.

Currently, the component rerenders but is unable to grab the new information during rerender given the new PIN_ID.

I am wondering if the Pinterest API allows such a feature, or it only supports on DOM load.